# Store a mongodb document inside another document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save MongoDB document from one collection to another collection. Iw want to it look like this when retrieving via my API endpoint. I create errors separately and want to join it with machine via id.

```
{
    "_id": "59634780c464263b28a6891a",
    "name": "GLUE-SM-21",
    "status": false,
    "__v": 0,
    "error": {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59769b9ad1050f244cadfced"),
        "count" : 5,
        "name" : "Error-001-J",
        "__v" : 0
    }
}
```

But I am getting this.

```
{
    "_id": "59634780c464263b28a6891a",
    "name": "GLUE-SM-21",
    "status": false,
    "__v": 0,
    "error": [
        "59769b9ad1050f244cadfced"
    ]
}
```

Here I am attaching my current work.

**Error Schema**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var ErrorSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    count: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Error', ErrorSchema);
```

**Machine Schema**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

var Error = require('./error');

var MachineSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    status: Boolean,
    error: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Error', default: null }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Machine', MachineSchema);
```

In the default case There is no error. Here is my save code.

```
        var machine = new Machine();        // create a new instance of the Machine model
        machine.name = req.body.name;  // set the machine name (comes from the request)
        machine.status = 1; // set the machine status (comes from the request)
        machine.error = null;

        machine.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Machine created!' });
        });
```

Here is my update code.

```
Machine.findById(req.params.machine_id, function(err, machine) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            machine.name = machine.name;

            if(req.body.error && machine.status) {
                machine.status = false;
            } else if(!req.body.error && !machine.status) {
                machine.status = true;
            }
            machine.error = req.body.error;
            machine.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);

                io.emit('machine', machine);

                res.json({ message: 'Machine updated!' });
            });

        });
```

Comment: The problem is that that `MachineSchema` "still" expects just an array of `ObjectId` to be stored. So even if you try to store in a different format, the "schema" will either error or "cast" to the registered types. You need to either register a new model with the **new** schema, **or** do your conversion in more "raw" code that does not use any schema at all. Then of course you need to register a schema that suits your new data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

I have saved object ID of error document inside my Machine document as error attribute. I have updated my code using **populate** function on mongo.

```
Machine.find().populate("error").exec(
            function(err, machines) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(machines);
        }
        );
```